# images are not displayed in drawable folder in android studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio

I am new to android programming, when I add an image to drawable folder, it is not displayed in the preview panel, and also my app when I run it. (I am using Android Studio 1.5.1)

This is how I added the image:
Right click on res, new Image Asset

On Asset type chose Action Bar and Tab Icons

Chose the image path

Give your image a name in Resource name

Next->Finish

but when I change "Action Bar and Tab Icons" to "launcher icons", I can see the image in different resolution in the preview panel.

Please help me. Is it possible to choose "launcher icons" instead of "Action Bar and Tab Icons"?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are adding images correctly using the Android Studio context menu.  Another way you can add images to drawable folder (if you are running on Windows OS) is to right click the drawable folder and choose "Show in Explorer".  Then you can drag and drop the images directly into the drawable folder.  I would imagine on Mac OS there is something comparable to access the folder structure directly.

Also please be sure to name your images with no spaces, or capital letters (underscore is OK).  PNG format and JPG format are OK to use.

You may also want to look into supporting multiple screen sizes:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You'll find the nine patch generator helpful for supporting multiple screen sizes:
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel comfortable with creating launcher or notifications icon, always you can choose this site: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

This great site would generate needed templates for you. Your role would be just unpack created zip and copy its content to `res` folder.

Instead of using Android Studio context menu, try to find the folder with your app resources. and check what every folder contains.

I also advice you to follow this Android course: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa

This would teach you in easy way about layouts, screen sizes and densities and much more. Of course, it would be provided example by example

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the images i.e. the png or jpg files into the drawable folder instead of copying  the folder that contains them into readable folder. It should work. Nesting folders make it difficult for android studio to index the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the image file directly into the `app_name/app/src/main/res/drawable` directory.

This worked for me.